# Help identifying this archival NACA/NASA image of a wind tunnel test object

Tags: nasa, history, identify-this-object

Near the end of the NASA video [Rocket Engine Testing the NASA Way!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RiPzzA281E0) there is an image that appears to be archival an possibly quite old. It's a metal model of a launch vehicle with two very long boosters, probably for testing in a supersonic wind tunnel.

Can anyone recognize this object, what the purpose is or what experiment is being done, and say a little more about how it was used?

[image: screen shot from Rocket Engine Testing the NASA Way!]

Comment: This question has a companion: [Help identifying this archival NACA/NASA image of a long liquid-cooled hollow tube object](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35967/12102)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a [model of the SLS](https://www.nasa.gov/exploration/systems/sls/multimedia/gallery/sls-payload-configurations.html).

> ASA engineers and contractors tested four different payload configurations during the liftoff transition testing of a 67.5-inch model of the SLS at NASA Langley Research Center’s 14-by-22-foot subsonic wind tunnel in Hampton, Va.

Comment: Ah, I thought there were four side boosters grouped as two pairs because it looks like four nozzles, but looking at the image in your link, there are two, and each has a double-nozzle-like appearance.